# Border Doesn't Draw in NSView When inside NSTableCellView

Tags: cocoa, nsview, cgcolor

I have three `NSView`s inside an `NSTableCellView`. Depending on the data for the row, I want to show a selected role with a border on the `NSView` like this:

[image]

The blue border `NSView` is a subclass that looks like this:

```
class RolePill: NSView{
  override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)  {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)
    layer?.cornerRadius = 9
    layer?.borderWidth = 2
    layer?.borderColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor
  }
}
```

The role gets set initially when my table loads like this:

```
extension UsersVC: NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource{
  func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "UserCell"), owner: nil) as! UserCell

    let user = users[row]

    //Role
    cell.setRole(role: user.role)
  }
}
```

And my table cell, where the role gets set on load and on a button click, is set up like this:

```
class UserCell: NSTableCellView{
  @IBOutlet weak var wrapOwner: RolePill!
  @IBOutlet weak var wrapAdmin: RolePill!
  @IBOutlet weak var wrapUser: RolePill!

  @IBAction func clickOwner(_ sender: NSButton) {
    setRole(role: "owner")
  }
  @IBAction func clickAdmin(_ sender: NSButton) {
    setRole(role: "admin")
  }
  @IBAction func clickUser(_ sender: NSButton) {
    setRole(role: "user")
  }
  
  func setRole(role: String){
    let selectedColor = getAccentColor()
    let offColor = Color(named: "BravoDark")!
    let offTextColor = Color(named: "BFC0C2")
    
    switch role{
      case "owner":
        wrapOwner.layer?.borderColor = selectedColor.cgColor
        wrapAdmin.layer?.borderColor = offColor.cgColor
        wrapUser.layer?.borderColor = offColor.cgColor
      
        labelOwner.textColor = Color.white
        labelAdmin.textColor = offTextColor
        labelUser.textColor = offTextColor
      case "admin":
        wrapOwner.layer?.borderColor = offColor.cgColor
        wrapAdmin.layer?.borderColor = selectedColor.cgColor
        wrapUser.layer?.borderColor = offColor.cgColor
        
        labelOwner.textColor = offTextColor
        labelAdmin.textColor = Color.white
        labelUser.textColor = offTextColor
        
      default:
        wrapOwner.layer?.borderColor = offColor.cgColor
        wrapAdmin.layer?.borderColor = offColor.cgColor
        wrapUser.layer?.borderColor = selectedColor.cgColor
      
        labelOwner.textColor = offTextColor
        labelAdmin.textColor = offTextColor
        labelUser.textColor = Color.white 
    }
    
  }
}
```

When the table loads initially, and anytime it refreshes (`tableView.reloadData()`) I lose my border and it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the `textColor` is set correctly to white. But for some reason, the border isn't set until I actually click on one of the `IBAction` buttons and manually trigger a change.

I suspect this is some kind of layer drawing bug where the `RolePill` class is redrawing every time my `NSTableView` reloads, but I don't know how to get it to accept the initial role state sent in `tableView viewForRow`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `user.role`?

Comment: `user.role` is a `String` that is either `owner`, `admin`, or `user`.

Comment: Do you redraw the cells when `role` changes?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by setting all the `NSView` properties inside `setRole()` like this:

```
view.wantsLayer = true
view.layer?.cornerRadius = 11
view.layer?.borderWidth = 2
view.layer?.borderColor = getAccentColor().cgColor

label.textColor = Color.white
```

It seemed that the `draw()` method on my `RolePill` subclass was getting called frequently, so I couldn't set a border color in there since it doesn't know what the user's data state is.

Comment: Do you ever set `wantsLayer`, `cornerRadius` and `borderWidth` to something else?

Comment: No, I don't. I suspect they could live in the `NSView` subclass.